# Need help deleting items from ArrayList that have been added by scanner

Tags: java, string, input, arraylist

I'm creating a program that will insert user input from a scanner (Strings, titles of songs to be exact) into an arrayList. I can insert them fine but I also want to create another class that will delete songs from the arrayList. Is there any way that I can delete specific songs or will I have to just delete the first position in the array? And if I did that would the arrayList shift positions so position 1 would become position 0 etc. or would position 1 stay position 1 and position 0 would be empty? My code for adding songs to the ArrayLists:

```
import java.util.*;

public class addSongs {

    public static void main (String[]args){

        Scanner songAdd = new Scanner(System.in);
        Scanner addContinue = new Scanner(System.in);
        String ceaseAdd = new String();
        ceaseAdd = "Y";

        while(ceaseAdd.equals("Y")){
                System.out.println("Enter track title");
                    String newSong = songAdd.nextLine();
                        MP3_catalogue.title.add(newSong);
                System.out.println("Enter artist name");
                    String newArtist = songAdd.nextLine();
                        MP3_catalogue.artist.add(newArtist);
                System.out.println("Enter duration");
                    String newDuration = songAdd.nextLine();
                        MP3_catalogue.duration.add(newDuration);
                System.out.println("Would you like to add another song? Y/N");
            ceaseAdd = addContinue.nextLine().toUpperCase();
        }

        MP3_catalogue obj = new MP3_catalogue();
    }

}
```

EDIT: the class above adds songs to the arrayLists by using a scanner to change the variables newSong, newArtist, newDuration, and then loops again to change the same variables to different input. Does arrayList save the content of the variable, ie the specific string entered or does it just save the variable ie newSong? If it just saves newSong surely I would have an arrayList with the same content filling it.

Answer (score 1):

Just check the [ArrayList Javadoc](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/ArrayList.html).

I think `ArrayList.remove(Object)` is what you are looking for.

Answer (score 0):

`ArrayList`s support random access. So yes, you can remove a specified item. See the [Javadoc](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/ArrayList.html#remove%28java.lang.Object%29).

Regarding your second question (the one in your later edit), this is a typical question related to parameter passing in Java.

When passing `newSong` to the `add` method, you're actually passing the reference of the `String` object. So this has nothing to do with the variable used to reference it, i.e. `newSong`. Anyway, `newSong` exits its scope as soon as the loop iteration completes. At the next iteration, the variable will be initialized again, but that won't change the content of your list.

So, to give a short answer: it stores the string entered.